# Criacao de BD com MySql - MariaDB - Workbench

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estou tentando criar um BD conforme Diagrama feito no Workbench porem retorna o erro a baixo:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 45: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
CONSTRAINT `fk_funcionario_cargo`
FOREIGN KEY (`cargo_idcargo`)
REFER' at line 8
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

SQL:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12` ;
USE `trabalhoa12` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12`.`projeto` (
  `idprojeto` INT NOT NULL,
  `descproj` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `orcamento` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idprojeto`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12`.`cargo` (
  `idcargo` INT NOT NULL,
  `cargo` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `salario` DECIMAL(8,2) NULL COMMENT ' ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcargo`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12`.`funcionario` (
  `idfuncionario` INT NOT NULL,
  `cargo_idcargo` INT NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `uf` CHAR(2) NULL,
  `cidade` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idfuncionario`, `cargo_idcargo`),
  INDEX `fk_funcionario_cargo_idx` (`cargo_idcargo` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_funcionario_cargo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cargo_idcargo`)
    REFERENCES `trabalhoa12`.`cargo` (`idcargo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = ndbcluster;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12`.`projeunc` (
  `projeto_idprojeto` INT NOT NULL,
  `funcionario_idfuncionario` INT NOT NULL,
  `reponsabilidade` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tempolotacao` DECIMAL(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projeto_idprojeto`, `funcionario_idfuncionario`),
  INDEX `fk_projeunc_funcionario1_idx` (`funcionario_idfuncionario` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projeunc_projeto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`projeto_idprojeto`)
    REFERENCES `trabalhoa12`.`projeto` (`idprojeto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projeunc_funcionario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`funcionario_idfuncionario`)
    REFERENCES `trabalhoa12`.`funcionario` (`idfuncionario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, o Banco de Dados é MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na criação dos índices `fk_funcionario_cargo_idx` e `fk_projeunc_funcionario1_idx` retire a opção `VISIBLE`. Por definição os índices do MySql são visiveis. Se quiser alterar a visibilidade de um índice use o comando `ALTER TABLE` se quiser criar um índice invisível o faça com `CREATE INDEX`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12`.`funcionario` (
  `idfuncionario` INT NOT NULL,
  `cargo_idcargo` INT NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `uf` CHAR(2) NULL,
  `cidade` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idfuncionario`, `cargo_idcargo`),

  INDEX `fk_funcionario_cargo_idx` (`cargo_idcargo` ASC),


  CONSTRAINT `fk_funcionario_cargo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cargo_idcargo`)
    REFERENCES `trabalhoa12`.`cargo` (`idcargo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = ndbcluster;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabalhoa12`.`projeunc` (
  `projeto_idprojeto` INT NOT NULL,
  `funcionario_idfuncionario` INT NOT NULL,
  `reponsabilidade` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tempolotacao` DECIMAL(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projeto_idprojeto`, `funcionario_idfuncionario`),

  INDEX `fk_projeunc_funcionario1_idx` (`funcionario_idfuncionario` ASC),

  CONSTRAINT `fk_projeunc_projeto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`projeto_idprojeto`)
    REFERENCES `trabalhoa12`.`projeto` (`idprojeto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projeunc_funcionario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`funcionario_idfuncionario`)
    REFERENCES `trabalhoa12`.`funcionario` (`idfuncionario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Certo! Resolvido!